# custom values in slider input shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want to use slider input (with animation) and move through years (1600-2013) in my dataset. The problem is that my data is heavily negatively skewed which is why I want to customize the 'step' incrementation inside my slider input. That means, I want something like

```
sequence <- c(1600,1700,1750,1800,1850,1900,1930,1950,1960,1970,1980,1990,1995,
             2000,2001,2003,2005,2006,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013)
```

instead of

```
sequence <- seq(1600,2013,by=1)
```

if the step size = 1.

Is there a way ?

Comment: Its not currently supported https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/1 . The underlying library https://github.com/egorkhmelev/jslider might be able to approximate what you want with scale and heterogeneity properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like a `log` scaling to determine where you sample points from, e.g.:

```
x <- log(seq(1,100,length.out=24))
scx <- scale(x,center=min(x),scale=diff(range(x)))
out <- round(scx * length(sequence))
out[1] <- 1

sequence[out]
# [1] 1600 1749 1802 1836 1860 1879 1895 1908 1920 1930 1939 1948 1955
#[14] 1962 1969 1975 1981 1986 1991 1996 2001 2005 2009 2013
```

It's not exactly what you are asked for, but it approximates it. If you change the function to use something other than `log` you may be able to get closer to your exact request.